# Best way to handle changes of <select>

Tags: javascript, java, html

On my main page (index.html) I have a list of some objects which have a category field for example. And on top of page I have  element selecting category. So, what is best way to handle it like this: when changes selected category in  - change a list of objects (view only objects with selected category).
Can I make it using only Java+Spring+Thymeleaf or I have to use JavaScrypt or other tool also?

UPDATE: My code

```
    <div class="grid-30">
        <select id="selectCategory" th:field="${selected.id}">
            <option th:each="category : ${allCategories}" th:value="${category.id}" th:text="${category.name}">All Categories</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

so when  element changes I want it toggles move to url "/category/"+${selected.id}

Comment: Please provide us some of your code

Comment: Are you using jquery or another javascript library/framework?

Comment: Use `ajax` for loading the dropdown.

Comment: How use ajax? I'm newb in JS